# Java 8 groupingBy on generic collection

Tags: java, grouping

I'm rather new to Java generics and I have a problem using Java 8 `groupingBy`.

I need to implement a container of tweets which has the following interface:

```
public interface TweetsContainer<T extends Tweet> extends Iterable<T>, Serializable {
...
    Map<String, Collection<T>> groupByLang();
...
}
```

`Tweet` is my own class with properly implemented `hashcode`, `equals`, etc.

Here is my attempt to implement method `groupByLang`:

```
public class LinkedListTweetsContainer<T extends Tweet> implements TweetsContainer<T> {
    private final List<T> tweets;
...
    @Override
    public Map<String, Collection<T>> groupByLang() {
        Map<String, Collection<T>> res =
            tweets.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(T::getLang));
        return res;
    }
...
}
```

However, I get an error at `T::getLang`, saying

```
Error:(51, 36) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<T>>
    upper bounds: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Collection<T>>,java.lang.Object
```

`Tweet` class has public method `getStringID`:

```
public class Tweet implements Serializable {
...
    public String getLang() { return lang; }
...
}
```

What does the error mean and what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

@Radiodef, thanks for your answer, but I wanted to dig into a question a bit deeper. List **is** a Collection, isn't it? I know term covariance --  when we have classes A, B, B extends A, and we are talking about inheritance of `GenericClass<A>` and `GenericClass<B>`. Here we have the opposite situation: the same parametrized type, but different (nested) generic classes. What are Java rules in this case, or what keywords/terms should I keep in mind if I want to read about it myself?

Answer (score 0):

[`groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collects to a `Map<K, List<T>>`.

```
Map<String, List<T>> res =
//          ^^^^^^^
    tweets.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(T::getLang));
```